# What do you call something that you've bet on?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, if you're betting on a horse in a horse race, that horse is called your _____ horse.

Comment: It's called "the horse on which you bet".

Comment: Sometimes, just the possessive: "My horse came in last". People know it isn't actually your own horse.

Comment: "Lost cause", sadly.

Comment: If you favour ***one of the entrants / contestants*** in a competition, that knight or horse or whatever is your ***champion***. But if you want to restrict yourself to the context of betting and horse-racing, you might consider the more context-specific [***nap***.](https://www.freetips.com/betting-terms/nap/)

Comment: Or just *your horse,* as Weather Vane posted.

Comment: Awesome, thanks guys! Those are all good suggestions.

Comment: Whether a horse or team, it's your 'pick' - picked to win.

Answer (score 2):

Take out the ____ blank and you have the answer: The horse you bet on is "your horse."

The boxer I bet on is "my boxer" or "my guy."